# Compiled Nashorn output as Java class

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

Is it possible to convert Nashorn evaluated output of a Javascript into a Java Class file to be invoked later ? 
(like JSP --> Java--> Class file)

I have a Javascript file that is used by Nashorn to generate HTML output. The javascript file has different functions per components  to generate the HTML output for each of them. These component functions are invoked dynamically through a "renderServer" function that takes component name and JSON data for that component.

```
private ScriptEngine nashorn;
ScriptEngineManager scriptEngineManager = new ScriptEngineManager(null);
        this.nashorn = scriptEngineManager.getEngineByName("nashorn");  
         this.nashorn.eval(new FileReader(jsFile);
String compName="myComponent1";// Component 1 name 
String jsonData="{....}";// JSON data input for myComponent
String formatted = "JSON.parse('" + jsonData + "')";

String htmlRender = "renderServer(\"" + myComponent1 + "\"," + formatted + ");";

Object finalResult = nashorn.eval(htmlRender);
```

I want to generate the compiled output of the evaluation and invoke the java class like  instead of doing nashorn.eval every time  by passing the component name and input json. 
Is it possible to achieve it?

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: @Pointy: Really? It was possible with Rhino...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ?? You can "wrap" the JavaScript so that it can be called as if it were Java, but that's not the same as actually "compiling" the JavaScript. It was still JavaScript evaluated by Rhino, and from what I know about Nashorn I'm pretty sure that the evaluation approach is not that it translates to byte code.

Comment: That said I would imagine that the same approach would work to have a Java-like method call interface to JavaScript methods. It's been years since I've done that but I can probably find the source :)

Comment: @Pointy: That wasn't the case for Rhino. Rhino compiled the JavaScript code to JVM bytecode and executed it. You could ouput class files if you liked: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Projects/Rhino/JavaScript_Compiler I haven't delved into Nashorn, hence my question above.

Comment: Welp in my old code I/we just did simple delegation to a `ScriptEngine` instance. I don't recall whether I ever tried to use the java proxy approach. *edit* Ah well you are probably right, but I've only ever used Rhino via the `ScriptEngine` interface. Nashorn (to my knowledge) is only exposed via that interface. There was a presentation about how the innards work at a Strange Loop a few years ago, and it seemed significantly different from Rhino.

Comment: @Pointy: Yeah, sounds like that's the case. You can get a `CompiledScript` instance for it, but I don't immediately see a way to write that out to a class file (and I don't seem to see a standalone for it). Pity. And of course, Rhino is quite out of date, JS-wise.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is no way to persist bytecode generated by nashorn and use it like a normal Java class. There is an undocumented/unsupported "--persistent-code-cache" to enable disk cache of compiled scripts - but that is still used internally by Nashorn. You can't load those classes by arbitrary class loader and call methods on it from your java code.

Comment: Is the --persistent-code-cache" to be used in jjs command to try?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But please note that this is an undocumented/unsupported option.